# Software to draw complex structures

Tags: tikz-pgf

Throughout my experience using LaTeX, I have used many packages but I've only compiled simple plots using `tikz-pgf` and derived packages such as `circuitikz`.

However most of the time I've found myself under situations that involve complex graphics and I wasn't able to draw them. I have tried several drawing packages that import the code to LaTex with little to no results.

What software should I use if want to draw complex plots like the one in the picture below?

[image]

This image has been done in LaTeX alongside the whole document. Here is a [link](http://www.teses.usp.br/teses/disponiveis/43/43134/tde-01072010-141132/publico/TesePhD_Henry_Javier_Ccallata.pdf) to download it. (pdf)

Comment: There is no evidence from the pdf that the *picture* was produced with LaTeX. Rather, it is plausible that a vector graphic version of the picture has first been produced using some dedicated sw and then the graphics was simply included in a LaTeX doc with an `\includegraphics`

Comment: For pictures like those, a 3D modeling sw seems appropriate. There are many available, including some free versions as Google SketchUp

Comment: Once you produced the main graphic element with some sw and exported in some vector image (like a PDF) then you can use `tikz` to annotate it with labels and captions so that the fonts and style used in the main text will match the ones in the picture

Comment: Why doesn't the link allow viewing the PDF in my browser the way most PDFs do? I just cancelled it. I don't trust documents with minds of their own.

Comment: This site encourages [specific questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) accompanied by a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).  Questions in the format of »What do you recommend?« are are off-topic as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.  I'm therefore voting to close.